# How to make This if?

Tags: python, file, if-statement

How to check content in file?

```
example : if Hello in file.txt
then print("Yes")
```

Please tell me this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for line in open("file.txt"):
 if "Hello" in line:
   print "Yes"
   break
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it, very bare-bones:

```
for line in open("file.txt"):
  if "Hello" in line:
    print "Yes"
    break
```

Iterating over a file object means iterating over its lines.

Comment: Wohoo, exactly same sample in one minute lately. :)